# Как вывести число которое начинается на цифру

Tags: php

Выведите на экран только те числа из массива, которые начинаются на цифру 1, 2 или 5.

```
$arr =  ['10', '20', '30', '50', '235', '3000'];
foreach( $arr as $elem ){
    echo $elem.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: приведите числа в массиве (у вас строки) к строке, проверьте первый символ строки при выводе. Если подходят, то выводите, а нет - пропускайте.

Comment: если без строк, то делите число нацело на 10 в степени "длина -1" (или целая часть десятичного логарифма), и проверяйте что получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
foreach ($arr as $elem) {
    if (in_array(substr($elem, 0, 1), [1, 2, 5])) {
        //..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Варианты работают как с массивом строк, так и с массивом чисел

До **PHP 7.4**

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr,function($item) {
   return in_array(((string)$item)[0],[1,2,5]);
});
```

После **PHP 7.4**

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr,fn($item)=> in_array(((string)$item)[0],[1,2,5]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через приведение к строке:

```
foreach($arr as $elem){
    $elem=(string) $elem;
    if($elem[0]==1 or $elem[0]==2 or $elem[0]==5){
        echo $elem.' ';
    }
}
```

Вариант через вычисление первой цифры:

```
foreach($arr as $elem){
    $start=($elem/10**(strlen($elem)-1))%10;
    //echo $start.' ';//получим первую цифру 1 2 3 5 2 3
    if($start==1 or $start==2 or $start==5){
       echo $elem;
    }
}
```